# Where are the code examples for connecting your tests to Sauce Connect?

Tags: webdriver, saucelabs

I've read the:  [Sauce Labs: Connect page](https://saucelabs.com/docs/connect)

and looked through Internet but I can't find any documentation on how to convert my Selenium tests to use Sauce Connect.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Dave

Comment: Maybe you could add a useful comment when you down-vote?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, Sauce Connect will be available via `http://localhost:4445`, so you should just need to change your tests from:

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + username + ":" + accessKey + "@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

to:

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + username + ":" + accessKey + "@localhost:4445/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

You shouldn't need to change your actual test logic when running tests with Sauce Connect.

I've created a [demo project](https://github.com/rossrowe/sauce-ci-java-demo), which primarily demonstrates how to construct tests to work with the Sauce plugins for Jenkins and Bamboo, but also includes a [sample SauceConnectTest](https://github.com/rossrowe/sauce-ci-java-demo/blob/master/src/test/java/SauceConnectTest.java) which asserts that tests can be run against a local website with Sauce Labs using Sauce Connect.

Comment: Does this mean my test need to be run on the same box as SauceConnect?

Comment: No, if Sauce Connect is launched on another server, then you just need to reference that server URL, eg.  new URL("http://" + username + ":" + accesskey + "@some.other.host:4445/wd/hub")

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  i should note that the SauceLabs online documentation does not give this answer in this much detail.  Thanks.

Comment: Saucelabs online documentation still doesn't have this info even after 3 years. Thanks for detailed info

Answer (score 0):

To initialize the webDriver use this:

```
WebDriver webDriver = null;
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + username + ":" + accessKey + "@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Now test the site, whatever you need, lets say you need google:

```
webDriver.get("http://www.google.com");
```